# What is the best way to set up a Spring JPA to handling searching for items based on tags?

Tags: database, spring, jpa, search, many-to-many

I am trying to set up a search system for a database where each element (a code) in one table has tags mapped by a Many to many relationship. I am trying to write a controller, "search" where I can search a set of tags which basically act like key words, giving me an element list where the elements all have the specified tags. My current function is incredibly naive, basically it consists of retrieving all the codes which are mapped to be a tag, then adding those a set, then sorting the codes by how many times the tags for each code is found in the query string.

```java
  public List<Code> naiveSearch(String queryText) {
    String[] tagMatchers = queryText.split(" ");
    Set<Code> retained = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(tagMatchers.length, 4); i++) {
      tagRepository.findAllByValueContaining(tagMatchers[i]).ifPresent((tags) -> {
        tags.forEach(tag -> {
              retained.addAll(tag.getCodes());
            }
        );
      });
    }
    SortedMap<Integer, List<Code>> matches = new TreeMap<>();
    List<Code> c;
    for (Code code : retained) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (String tagMatcher : tagMatchers) {
        for (Tag tag : code.getTags()) {
          if (tag.getValue().contains(tagMatcher)) {
            sum += 1;
          }
        }
      }
      c = matches.getOrDefault(sum, new ArrayList<>());
      c.add(code);
      matches.put(sum, c);
    }
    c = new ArrayList<>();
    matches.values().forEach(c::addAll);
    Collections.reverse(c);
    return c;

  }
```

This is quite slow and the overhead is unacceptable. My previous trick was a basically retrieval on the description for each code in the CRUDrepository

```
public interface CodeRepository extends CrudRepository<Code, Long> {

  Optional<Code> findByCode(String codeId);
  Optional<Iterable<Code>> findAllByDescriptionContaining(String query);

}
```

However this is brittle since the order of tags in containing factors into whether the result will be found. eg. I want "tall ... dog" == "dog ... tall"

Comment: Is it possible to search it using sql / jpql directly ?

Comment: Yes i can write "native query" in the repository

Comment: here is something....
https://medium.com/@pankajsewalia/in-memory-search-engine-service-using-spring-boot-3face81a1cfd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So okay, I'm back several days later with how I actually solved this problem. I used [hibernate's built in search library](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.11/#get-it) which has a very easy implementation in spring. Just paste the required maven coordinates in your POM.xml and it was ready to roll.

First I removed the manytomany for the tags<->codes and just concatenated all my tags into a string field. Next I added @Field to the tags field and then wrote a basic search Method. The method I wrote was a very simple search function which took a set of "key words" or tags then performed a boolean search based on fuzzy terms for the the indexed tags for each code. So far it is pretty good. My database is fairly small (100k) so I'm not sure about how this will scale, but currently each search returns in about 20-50 ms which is fast enough for my purposes.